# Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to add a `UserControl` to a `ListBox`, how do I add it?

```
public void studentsToList()
{
    ListBox items = new ListBox();
    StudentListItem roundItem = new StudentListItem();
    for (int x = 0; x < students.Count; x++)
    {
        roundItem.uc_txtStudentNumber.Content += Convert.ToString(students[x].Student_Number);
        roundItem.uc_txtSurname.Content += Convert.ToString(students[x].Student_Name);
        roundItem.uc_txtSurname.Content += Convert.ToString(students[x].Student_Gender);

        items.Items.Add(roundItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the declaration of StudentListItem inside your for loop becaue currently you are adding the same instance of StudentListItem multiple times to the ListBox.

```
public void studentsToList()
{
    ListBox items = new ListBox();

    for (int x = 0; x < students.Count; x++)
    {
        StudentListItem roundItem = new StudentListItem();

        roundItem.uc_txtStudentNumber.Content += Convert.ToString(students[x].Student_Number);
        roundItem.uc_txtSurname.Content += Convert.ToString(students[x].Student_Name);
        roundItem.uc_txtSurname.Content += Convert.ToString(students[x].Student_Gender);
        items.Items.Add(roundItem);
    }
}
```